# I want to change the host account for Google app email?

Tags: email

I have a standard (free) Google app Email Service. In the last 5 months, we have been using this service. Our website was hosted at a third party web hosting company. Now  I am planning to change my web hosting provider. I want to keep my domain at the previous hosting company.  Can Google Apps allow this option of changing  web hosting for the registered Domain in the Google App for Email Service?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the dns records.

**If you're changing your domain provider:**
Just copy all your mx records for mail from the old domain to the new domain (write down what they are before you transfer, and add them into the new domain after the transfer), also copy the cname record for your google verification, and any other cnames relating to your google apps (they're all pointing to ghs.google.com)

**If You're changing only your host:**
Keeping a domain with one provider and not another is fine, you won't need to change anything other than the ns records and an a record relating to where the domain points, this won't mess with google apps at all.